# Why is $P(X \leq Y) = \mathbb{E}_Y[P(X \leq y)]$?

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be independent. I am trying to find $P(X \leq Y)$. Although these are continuous R.V.'s, I have intuition that one must "sum up" all $X \leq y$, weighted by the probability that $Y = y$. So I get the following equation:
 $$P(X \leq Y) = \mathbb{E}_Y[P(X \leq y)]$$
However I cannot seem to justify why it would be true. Is there a proof somewhere of this fact or a more general fact?

Comment: It should follow if you write both sides as integrals for example (it doesn’t seem that $X$ or $Y$ have to be continuous for this to work)

Comment: You can use the law of total probability (in integral form) by conditioning on $\{Y=y\}$: $$P[X\leq Y] = \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} P[X \leq Y|Y=y] f_Y(y)dy = \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} P[X \leq y|Y=y]f_Y(y)dy = \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} P[X \leq y] f_Y(y)dy$$ where the last equality is by independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By independence the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is given by the product of the marginals and hence $$P(X \leq Y)=\iint I_{x\leq y} \,dF_X(x)\,dF_Y(y).$$ Just apply Fubini's Theorem integrating w.r.t. $F_X$ first and then w.r.t. $F_Y$.

Comment: It might be worth to note that you are using independence here as $F_{X,Y}=F_X \cdot F_Y$

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ were a discrete integer valued Random variable the Law of Total Probability would say:$$\mathsf P(X<Y)=\sum_{y\in\Bbb N}\mathsf P(X<Y\mid Y=y)~\mathsf P(Y=y)$$

If $Y$ were a continuous real valued Random variable, with density function $f_Y(~)$, the Law of Total Probability would say:$$\mathsf P(X<Y)=\int_{\Bbb R}\mathsf P(X<Y\mid Y=y)~f_Y(y)~{\mathrm d y}$$

We generalise these results as the expectation of the conditional probability of $X<Y$ over given values for $Y$, and *might* use the notation $\mathsf E_Y(\mathsf P(X<Y))$ for this.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf P(X<Y\mid Y))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E_Y(\mathsf P(X<Y))\end{align}$$